# Using {knitr} spin function ignores chunk options

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm having trouble compiling a `spin`-annotated R script to HTML/PDF.

Here's a MWE:

```
#' ---
#' output:
#'     html_document:
#'         toc: true
#'         toc_float: true
#'     pdf_document:
#'         toc: true
#' jupyter:
#'   jupytext:
#'     text_representation:
#'       extension: .R
#'       format_name: spin
#'       format_version: '1.0'
#'       jupytext_version: 0.8.4
#'   kernelspec:
#'     display_name: R
#'     language: R
#'     name: ir
#'   language_info:
#'     codemirror_mode: r
#'     file_extension: .r
#'     mimetype: text/x-r-source
#'     name: R
#'     pygments_lexer: r
#'     version: 3.6.0
#' ---
#+ setup, include=F, echo=F
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse=T)

#+ error=T
.3 <- 5

#' some text

#+ error=T
for <- 5
```

The script was created from a jupyter notebook running the R kernel. The conversion was done using `jupytext`.

The build fails with this error:

```
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = TRUE) : 
  <text>:122:5: unexpected assignment
121: #+ error=T
122: for <-
         ^
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> getParseData -> parse
Execution halted
```

This is an excerpt from an R workshop, and represents faulty variable naming, so the errors are expected. Hence the `error=T` chunk options.

What puzzles me the most is that (i) this script compiled earlier with no problems (last successful build was on December, 5th 2018; haven't tried rebuilding until now), and (ii) `.3 <- 5` is just as wrong, but R is complaining only about the second line.

I'm compiling the document to HTML using:

```
 Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("filename.R", output_format = "html_document")'
```

Running on R v3.6, and `4.14.113-1-MANJARO` Linux, `knitr` is v1.22, `rmarkdown` is v1.12 (as per `sessionInfo`).

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `.3 <- .5` is syntactically correct, but `for <- 5` is not.

The first of these would generate a run-time error.  Generally the left-hand side of an assignment can be an expression, and that's how things like `x[1] <- 3` are parsed.  It's just that not all expressions will be allowed at evaluation time.

The `for <- 5` line is not parseable (because `for` is a reserved word), so the error would happen at parse time.  Syntax errors are generally signalled with messages like "unexpected...", as you saw:

```
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = TRUE) : 
  <text>:122:5: unexpected assignment
121: #+ error=T
122: for <-
         ^
```

If you notice the line number, this is line 122 of the text being parsed.  Perhaps in earlier versions of `knitr` the parsing was done chunk-by-chunk, but now the whole file is parsed before any parts are evaluated:  and that line won't parse.

If you write the whole thing as an Rmd file, you'll get the previous behaviour, because in those the chunks **are** parsed one at a time:

````
---
output:
    html_document:
        toc: true
        toc_float: true
---
```{r setup, include=F, echo=F}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse=T)
```

```{r error=T}
.3 <- 5
```

some text

```{r error=T}
for <- 5
```
````

[image]

Comment: Ah, sorry. The line number is a leftover from the original file. I've trimmed it down to only contain the code in the question, but copied an older error message. Running the `render` command on the code above gives the same error with the correct line number.

But I guess it's possible something's changed in {knitr}. Guess I'll have to hardcode this part of the file. I'll accept your answer if someone doesn't show up with a working solution.

Comment: I *did* give you a working solution:  use `.Rmd`, not `.R`.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is - there's an interconnected system of files sourced from the same jupyter notebook, and it's less work to just hardcode that part than to rearrange the whole system just to be able to go around this one error message. So switching to `.Rmd` is not something I'd consider doing at the time. But you are right, that *is* a possible solution.

Comment: You can't `source()` that file.  It does what `knitr` does:  parse the whole thing, then evaluate.